# groupby/merge to the latest record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

Table1: Food_I_Have_In_Fridge:

```
Food  | Category
---------------
Apple | Fruit
Beef  | Meat
Tomato| Veggie
Pork  | Meat
Bacon | Meat
Orange| Fruit
Carrot| Veggie
```

Table2: Food_I_ate:

```
Date | Food
------------
Mon  | Apple
Mon  | Beef
Tues | Pork
Thurs| Orange
Sat  | Tomato
```

I want to generate a list of last things I ate categorized by the food category.  The output looks like:

```
Categ| Food
-----------
Meat | Pork
Fruit| Orange
Veggi| Tomato
```

I havn't been able to group & merge rows, any suggestions?

thanks!

Comment: they are 'overwritten' by Pork and Orange. Because the last fruit I ate was Orange and last meat I ate was Pork.

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?. Also, is the `Date` really only a part of the week day?, or is a proper `DATE/DATETIME` column?

Comment: Test schema: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b92f

Comment: @mellamokb - I'm really hoping that `[Date]` is not like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really *are* using names of weekdays for your date column, here is a solution which will translate the weekdays to weekday indices and find the latest food by category:

```
;with FW as (
    select w.ix, f.category, a.food, a.date
    from
        [Food_I_ate] a
    inner join
        [Food_I_Have_In_Fridge] f on a.Food = f.Food
    inner join
    (
        select 0 as ix, 'Sun' as weekdayname union
        select 1, 'Mon' union
        select 2, 'Tues' union
        select 3, 'Wed' union
        select 4, 'Thurs' union
        select 5, 'Fri' union
        select 6, 'Sat'
     ) w on w.weekdayname = a.[Date]
)
select
    FW2.category,
    FW2.Food,
    FW2.Date
from
    (select FW.category, max(fw.ix) as maxix
     from FW group by FW.category) FW
inner join
    FW FW2 on FW2.ix = FW.maxix and FW2.category = FW.category
```

Sample Output:

```
CATEGORY    FOOD    DATE
Veggie      Tomato  Sat
Meat        Pork    Tues
Fruit       Orange  Thurs
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b92f/21

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks! and no, my dates are not stored as days (that would be terrible), it's stored in datetime data type, but I used days of week for the sake of simplicity in this example and obviously it back fired.

Comment: Ya there is a point where trying to simplify your example is too far :)

Comment: quick question, is there a reason for `;with FW as` in the first line with a `;` in the front? I tried running the script without it, i get the same output. thanks!

Comment: The `;` causes all the previous SQL to be treated as an entire statement.  It works the same with or without unless you have SQL Code before the `with` statement, so I drop in a `;` in front by habit.

Comment: oh that's a great practice i really should start using it too. thanks @mellamokb :)